# Cordova capture video feed from device camera.

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a camera recording / editing app and so I installed https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

Plugin and got it working however this opens a dialog and requires the user to pick a platform to record the video and then it just returns the information. Since I want my app to do the recording I looked into
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

This seems to be what I want but only for images, is there a Cordova video recording plugin? Is it possible to use either of those above plugins?

Comment: try this --> https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin